# MySQL / MariaDB change feeds

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is there a way to get a notification when a row in a table is created or updated? Much like RethinkDB's change feeds.

Anything would work really - a message on a WS channel, or a HTTP request with the data that was created/updated...

Cannot use trigger to copy to temp table and poll, this is for a real time currency fx feed.

I've also been looking at reading from binlogs but it's too complicated, adds overhead and multiple possible points of failure.

Later edit: also tried `lib_mysqludf_sys` to `sys_exec()` a PHP script that connects to the WS server to send the update, it takes between .25 and .50 seconds, which is very very slow considering the single table I am interested in gets updated several thousand times per minute.

Comment: Can that notification come from the _client that does the insert/update_?

Comment: No. Wouldn't have posted this if that was a solution.

Comment: Never can tell; some questioners want things delivered on a silver platter.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and MariaDB do not have any way for a `TRIGGER` to invoke anything outside of the MySQL/MariaDB server.  (To do so would be to create a security problem.)

Well, you *could* write a `UDF` that could do anything, and compile a special version of the server, etc.

You are probably better off polling, as you mentioned.  If there are thousands of updates per minute, the polling could "optimize" the fetch via `GROUP BY` and other techniques.

Comment: Already tried playing with the UDF plugin and a PHP script that sends the WS message. It's not viable because the shell spawn, WS library load and so on take time, on occasion it shown 0.8s and triggers are synchronous - the script won't run in a separate thread, so all updates/inserts would get delayed by up to 1 second.... which is not an option. Polling is also not an option because I'd have to do it every half second or so to satisfy my use case. I am currently looking at writing a plugin, will see if something else pops up.

Comment: I think you are going to have to step back to the bigger picture and remove some of the design constraints/assumptions that you have.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is [Changed Data Capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture) - CDC.

These days there are better options for implementing such mechanisms for MariaDB / MySQL. You can e.g. look into the [CDC protocol for MariaDB MaxScale](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-maxscale-22-change-data-capture-cdc-protocol/) which is utilising the [MariaDB MaxScale AVRO router](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-maxscale-22-avrorouter/) to convert binlog events into AVRO files. The CDC protocol then makes the change data capture events available to registered clients.

**EDIT:** Please also see this answer: [Change Data Capture in Mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/189829/94242)